# Manually installing Koma script to MikTex

Tags: miktex, koma-script, installing

I'm having some problems with LaTex. I recently installed it to my computer, but do not have admin rights so did a local install to my user. I first installed MikTex, then installed TexMaker. I tried making a pdf from a .tex file I have saved from a scipt I made on my other computer. I got the following error: `LaTex Error: File 'scrartcl.cls' no found`. I looked into this and saw that this is from not having Koma-Script installed. So I went to https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script?lang=en to download the .zip file an unzipped it. I looked the README and INSTALL files, which say "MiKTeX users can easily install the current release of KOMA-Script using the self extracting archive for windows also known as MiKTeX installation file.  See http://www.komascript.de/current for more information. But if you want to install another release, you have to read the installation instructions below." I went to that page which led to https://komascript.de/node/2047. This page says to download a MD5 file that I then downloaded. I then opened MikTex Package Manager and found the Koma-script and tried to install it but got the error that "~/koma-script" is not a package repository. What am I doing wrong? I'm on Windows 10 if that affects anything

Comment: Why do you want to install manually instead of using the package manager of miktex?

Comment: I am using the package manager. Sorry, I will edit that. I meant manually install as in downloading the files then using the package manager as opposed to the package manager or TexMaker installing them from the web.

Comment: The zip-file is not a miktex package. You will need a file from here https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages if you want to install with the package manager. And you will need the two miktex-zz-files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a local repository on your hard disk and download the files you're interested in, plus the following files: `pr.ini`, `miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma`, `miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma` and `files.csv.lzma`. Then launch MPM, menu `Repository -> Change Package Repository…` and select `Packages shall be installed from a directory`:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghgpX.png)